# How do I access the data from a json call/request

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, response

I'm making a request to questions.json, but I'm unsure how to capture the data returned by the response call. The JSON file is just an object but when I try to call response.names to get it, it's telling me response is not defined? Didn't I define it when I called the json function on it?

I'm thinking maybe because it's a promise, it's not technically defined? Unsure.

Here's my code:

```
fetchQuestions();

function createCategory(category, questions) {
    const categoryDiv = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('category');
    const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    h2.textContent = category;
    categoryDiv.append(h2);
    questions.forEach(question => {
        const questionDiv = document.createElement('div');
        questionDiv.classList.add('question');
        const statusDiv = document.createElement('div');
        statusDiv.classList.add(questions.status);
        questionDiv.append(statusDiv);
        const h3 = document.createElement('h3');
        h3.textContent = question.name;
        questionDiv.append(h3);
        categoryDiv.append(questionDiv);
    });
    return categoryDiv;
}

function fetchQuestions() { 
    const myRequest = new Request('questions.json');
    fetch(myRequest)    
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(getQuestionsByCategory(response.names))
    .catch(console.error);
}

function getQuestionsByCategory(questions) {
    const questionsByCategory = {};
    questions.forEach(question => {
        if (questionsByCategory.hasOwnProperty(question.category)) {
            questionsByCategory[question.category].push(question);
        } else {
            questionsByCategory[question.category] = [question];
        }
    });
    return questionsByCategory;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between function as function and function as reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547407/difference-between-function-as-function-and-function-as-reference-in-javascript)

Comment: `getQuestionsByCategory(response.names)` is a function call that returns an object, but `.then` expects a function.

Comment: @jabaa am I correct in assuming that I can access the data in the json file by simply calling the object by its name? I.e. .then(data () => {for (const name in names) {//code here}. In this code, “names” is the object name in the json file.

Comment: No, that's not correct. It looks like you should read a basic tutorial first. You can wrap the function call with a lambda function `() => getQuestionsByCategory(response.names)`

Comment: @jabaa ah ok I understand, the promise returns an object and I can call that object. So since response is the name of the object (response.json()), I can call response.names like you said because I’m certain there’s a names property in the json file. Thanks a lot man, I don’t get much help as a beginner :p

Comment: @jabaa wait hold on, I’m not entirely confident with that comment. Let me do more research and potentially rephrase